# Refresh dynamic table content in Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a Bootstrap modal with a dynamic table in it.
Here is the button that triggers the modal popup:

```
<button class="orgBrowseButton">  <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Here is the function called when this button is clicked on. When it is clicked, an ajax call is performed and its response is an html page (see below after the function snippet), which is rendered as the body of the modal. You can see that I remove data from the modal, and the modal itself from my jsp, after the modal is closed:

```
$(".orgsBrowseButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'actionToCall.action',//this is a struts action
            jsCallback:function(data){
                callbackFunction(data);
            },
            cache: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $(data).insertAfter("#MainContentID");//a div in my jsp
            $(".modal").modal();
            $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
                $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
                $('.modal').remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

And this is the modal. This modal contains a form, and a table whose data derives from an ajax response. The code that generates the table is custom, so I cannot post it here. It's a dynamic table.

```
    <div class="modal" id="popup" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form class="form-horizontal" id="searchOrgsForm" action="" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="orgName"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="TableFilledWithDataThroughAjaxCall">
            </table>
         </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <button id="closeButton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So there are 2 ajax calls: one that returns the data to fill the body of the modal and one WITHIN the modal, which fills the datatable.

The problem is that the second time I open the modal, the data from the datatable is missing, although the ajax call is performed normally (I can see it in the server logs). The table seems not to reload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you perform this

```
$('.modal').remove();
```

removes the modal from DOM. on success of your ajax call javascript can't find the modal in DOM.

Solution:
instead of .remove() use .empty() to clear the modal's body

```
$('.modal-body').empty()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried that, but no luck...
The datatable is still missing its data

Comment: are you getting the datatable in your data variable of ajax success function ?

Comment: your are suppose to populate this div  with ID 
'#TableFilledWithDataThroughAjaxCall'
 what is this for 
'$(data).insertAfter("#MainContentID");' i dont understand

Comment: Yes, the data parameter contains the datatable.

The data in '$(data).insertAfter("#MainContentID");' is the data that comes from an ajax call (with url : actionToCall.action), and it contains all the html elements that are necessary for the modal body.

The table with id="TableFilledWithDataThroughAjaxCall" is the dynamic table that is filled with data from another ajax call. It is inside the elements necessary for the modal body (it is supposed to be reloaded every time I open the modal, but it isn't and that's my problem).

Comment: what is the 2nd ajax call where is it? share the complete code please. this is simple and nothing big to solve.

Comment: This table is generated with custom code belonging to the company I work in, I cannot share it here and even if I could it is very complicated to describe and it requires posting too much code. The only thing I can expose is that the table is dynamic, an ajax call is performed in order to fill it, and the json result returned is rendered in another jsp included in the jsp which contains the modal body.

Comment: 1) use .empty()   
2) you dont need to define $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) { again and again    , define it once globally    
3) run the dynamic table call in complete: function() body of ajax call and not in success

Comment: Thank you! I will try it

Comment: please mark this as answer if it helped you in your query